# Not modify package.json when doing npm audit fix

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

I've updated my npm version, and I think `npm audit` is a new feature. When I run `npm audit fix` some of my packages versions are changed from package.json. I just want keep the packages as same as my coworkers

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To answer the original question, if you really want to skip auditing completely when installing (for whatever reason, in my case I wanted to troubleshoot an exception when installing) you can use `--no-audit` flag:

```
npm install --no-audit
```

Answer (score 6):

npm audit fix is not must to get your app up and running. I use this command when I want to make sure that there is no potential security vulnerability so that git hub won't have any object against my project. In case you still want to use audit fix without changing rest files, try this commands

Run audit fix without modifying node_modules, but still updating the pkglock:

```
 $ npm audit fix --package-lock-only
```

Skip updating devDependencies:

```
  $ npm audit fix --only=prod
```

Do a dry run to get an idea of what audit fix will do, and also output install information in JSON format:

```
$ npm audit fix --dry-run --json
```

Check out this link for your future reference: 
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit

Comment: Unfortunately `npm audit fix --package-lock-only` changes `package.json` in certain cases. For example: you have referenced `react-script` version `3.2.0`, then even with the `--package-lock-only` flag it will update this package to version 3.3.0 or later.

Answer (score 0):

`npm audit`

1. Doesn't Update All packages. Only Vulnerable ones.
2. Doesn't update `package.json`
3. Has some bugs.

For that reason, I like to go with  npm package [ncu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates). In a fully functional project, with test cases written this works wonders.

Once `ncu` is installed, simply run `ncu --doctor -u` to update packages.

1. It updates npm packages to latest stable ones.
2. It runs test cases each time, it updates a package to report any breakage.